# WSO2 ESB How we can split Property's value and log after split chars?

Tags: arrays, properties, split, wso2, esb

I want get char after spilt messagetext !

```html
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="iterate" context="/tokenize">
   <resource methods="GET" uri-template="/{temp}">
      <inSequence>
        <property name="MessageText" value="a,b,c," scope="default"></property>
         <log>
           <property name="MessageText" expression="get-property('MessageText')"></property>
         </log>
        [how ergodic this MessageText?]
        <iterate continueParent="true" expression="MessageText" sequential="true">
            <target>
               <sequence>
                  <log level="full" separator=",">
                     <property name="arrayChar" value="?"></property>
                  </log>
               </sequence>
            </target>
         </iterate>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

I want result!
    arrayChar = a
    arrayChar = b
    arrayChar = c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iterate mediator need a list of xml nodes so, create a new XML message with the list of values extracted from your property 'MessageText' (the purpose of script mediator) and then, iterate the nodes from this message with iterate mediator

```
  <inSequence>
    <property name="MessageText" value="a,b,c" scope="default"/>
    <script language="js"><![CDATA[
        var payloadXML = new XML(<root/>);
        for each (var item in String(mc.getProperty("MessageText")).split(',')) {
            payloadXML.appendChild(new XML(<item>{item}</item>));
        }
        mc.setPayloadXML(payloadXML);
    ]]></script>
    <iterate xmlns:fn="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions" continueParent="true" expression="//item" sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <log level="full" separator=",">
                 <property name="arrayChar" expression="$body/item"></property>
              </log>
           </sequence>
        </target>
     </iterate>
 </inSequence>
```

Comment: While this may help the OP solve the problem, code-only answers typically aren't of much use to the community at-large.  Would you mind adding an explanation describing how this code answers the question?

Comment: thanks for you advise, for example,i receive a codes,the codes is separated by a comma,i want split codes by comma then goup it,and Request the corresponding interface separately,so we need this split method. My English is not very good,please forgive me!