# WSO2 Iterate over an array

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

Is it possible to iterate over an array (result of a fn:tokenize in my case) ?
I just want to enrich my payload depending on my array content. Of course, my array size is unknown ;)
WSO2 ESB 4.9.0

Thanks for your help

Comment: That should help: [https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+18%3A+Transforming+a+Message+Using+ForEach+Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/Sample+18%3A+Transforming+a+Message+Using+ForEach+Mediator).
Just use get-property('theTokenizeProperty') in your case as the arg expression.

Comment: Thanks for your help but I don't see how i can loop on my array in this sample :(

Comment: Somehow, I didn't manage to do the tokenize function, but here is another [stackoverflow post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36275320/wso2-esb-how-we-can-split-propertys-value-and-log-after-split-chars)
The issue is very similar and they have achieved it with the Script mediator instead. See, if this could help. Otherwise, it might be helpful if you post what you have until now (excluding sensitive data, if any), so that I could reproduce it and make some more attempts on solving it.

Comment: Sorry but tried a lot of things without success. So, I finally change to an XSLT Mediator instead of Enrich Mediator

Comment: My attempts also failed - I have no idea why, but couldn't make it work with both tokenize and get-property in the same proxy. I know that for tokenize I have to enable xpath 2.0 - I did that. I also know that I should use get-property with the syn prefix - I did that as well. But it keeps giving me  "No such function get-property" error. Sorry I couldn't help.

Comment: Thanks Maria for your attempts! I did the same tricks (activate xpath 2.0...) on my side.